# When will other sites follow Stack Overflow Portuguese

Tags: support, area-51, beta-sites, languages, internationalization

The first site using internationalization, [Stack Overflow Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), is now online for over 7 months.

What are the plans for other sites like this waiting to be launched at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com)? Will this be happening soon?

Comment: I'd expect that at a minimum, SE would have to add some  Community Managers who speak those languages... They are [currently looking](http://stackexchange.com/work-here) for CMs fluent in Spanish and Japanese. Unfortunately Anna Lear went from CM to development, which I guess is a setback for SO in Russian proposal...

Comment: You would probably get better support in http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/ since all those future sites are in there.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: But there are so many unanswered questions there... I feel like nobody is looking there

Comment: @juergend Are you interested in other sites being launched in non-English language, or are you interested in Stack Overflow being launched in other languages? (Or both?)

Comment: I am interested generally in the launch of non-English sites.

Answer (score 13):

Site proposals in other languages have continually been made since this question was asked - and for good reason!  The position that Stack Overflow has taken on these matters is that there needs to be a Stack Overflow site in the target language **first** before any other target language sites are added.  Once that site has increased in momentum and has graduated, other Stack Exchange sites will be considered and added as per the Area 51 processes.

The Stack Overflow in Spanish, for example, was awaiting a native language Community Manager.  Now that this person has been found, the site will continue on as all other proposal sites do.

You can read this informative post about [the future of International Sites here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20987/internationalization-state-of-the-stack-stack-overflow-edition).

You can also read about [the latest update on the Stack Overflow Spanish site here.](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12731/any-update-about-this-site)

Comment: I think you meant "The position that Stack Exchange has taken" (since that's the name of the company). Welcome to Meta!

Answer (score 10):

Until official answer is given, you can see for yourself by search http://area51.stackexchange.com for "Stack Overflow" which currently gives those sites at 100% commitment:

1. [Stack Overflow (in Spanish)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish)
2. [Stack Overflow (in Russian)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian)
3. [Stack Overflow (in Turkish)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34945/stack-overflow-in-turkish)
4. [Stack Overflow (in German)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54232/stack-overflow-in-german)

All of the above showing:

> This launch is on hold while we add the international features needed to make it functional for this community. Dates will be announced when available.

For example the Spanish site is probably awaiting a Community Manager to be recruited first, as can be seen [here](https://hire.jobvite.com/CompanyJobs/Careers.aspx?nl=1&k=Job&j=oNY1Yfwu&s=Careers_Site).

So we can just wait patiently, and slowly but surely those sites will arrive.

Related discussion: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/are-stack-overflow-in-language-x-proposals-actually-viable/5857#5857

Comment: [This comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236890/when-will-other-sites-follow-stack-overflow-portuguese#comment776600_236890) is pretty spot-on too. They won't create any of these sites until they have a Community Manager that would be able to handle them effectively.

Comment: Turkish is written in the Latin alphabet: no need to right to left support. (Of course case mapping might need fixing if it is not already done correctly….)

Comment: @animuson true, added into the answer.

Comment: @Richard oh, assumed it's like Arabic. Thanks, removed the wrong part.

Answer (score 2):

There are proposals for other sites in other languages:

[History (in Spanish)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/68616/history-in-spanish)
[Super User (in Spanish)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/68914/superuser-in-spanish)
[Matemáticas (Mathematics SE in Spanish)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64529/matematicas-mathematics-se-in-spanish)

However, none of these have much of a following at the moment.

You should be able to find others in other languages.

The system is that you propose a site on Area 51 and if it gains enough followers and sample questions it will proceed to the next stage of the process and then finally onto launch - once there is a community manager who is a native speaker of the language (the same as for Stack Overflow in Portuguese).