# Is there an option to change the language from Spanish to English?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, languages

I'm searching for an answer on Stack Overflow.
I found the following the website:

[Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/317804/attempt-to-invoke-interface-method-int-java-util-list-size-on-a-null-object)

Is there an option to change the language of this website to English?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, there is no such option as that is the Spanish Stack Overflow where Spanish is the primary / only language posts are allowed to be in, just like Stack Overflow proper only allows English posts.

See also [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676) and [International Stack Overflows: Unlimited, On Time, and Comprehensive in your native language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316522)

Use Google translate or another translate tool to convert the post to a language you master.

For your convenience I've had Chrome translate that post to English. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGHGh.png) is the screenshot.

I did find a similar looking question with answers on Stack Overflow:

[Android Studio Error : Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57907892/android-studio-error-attempt-to-invoke-interface-method-int-java-util-list-si)

That was the first hit in this search:

> [`[java] [android] [android-studio]  java.util.List.size() on a null object reference`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bandroid%5D+%5Bandroid-studio%5D++java.util.List.size%28%29%27+on+a+null+object+reference)

I basically copied the tags from that Spanish question and the error message that was already in English and crossed my fingers.  Sometimes you're lucky.

Answer (score 9):

It's a separate site. If the question doesn't exist on [Stack Overflow in English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions), you are welcome to re-ask the question there in English.

The non-English Stack Overflow sites are not translations, they're sites in different languages, with different intended audiences.